# Excel VBA exit sub if txt file modified today

Tags: excel, vba

I'm tying to stop the macro if a .txt file has been modified today (i.e. within the last 30s)s, below is my code but it gives an error 91 on the line `file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Logs.txt\"` whenever I try to run it. What am I missing? Thanks.

```
Sub Calculate()

Dim Fdate As Date
Dim FileInFromFolder As Object
Dim file As Object

file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Logs.txt\"

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

Fdate = file.Int(FileInFromFolder.DateLastModified)

If Fdate = Date Then GoTo eh
Else

'Minimize workbook
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized

'Switch to manual calculation of formulae
Application.Calculation = xlManual
ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Call Backup

Call Move

'Switch to automatic calculation of formulae
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Done:
    Exit Sub
eh:
    ' All errors will jump to here
    MsgBox "error test"
End Sub
```

Edit: added error location.

Comment: *it gives an error 91* Where? which line? Also, you declare `FileInFromFolder` but you don't assign it. Also, you are using `Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")` but you never declare FSO.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns it gives an error on the following line: `file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Logs.txt\"`. I'm not too familiar with vab so thnaks for pointing those out.

Comment: You are assigning a string to an object 'file'

Comment: You have to set your object variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you are saying the variable file is of type `Object`

`Dim file As Object`

And then you assign a string to it

`file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Logs.txt\"`

Which is not valid.

I'm guessing you are trying to get a file object from the path.

You can do that using the FileSystemObject you created (but didn't use)

```
dim fileName as String
Dim file As Object
Dim FSO as Object

fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Logs.txt"
set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set file = FSO.GetFile(fileName)
```

Comment: Yup, and to top it off > `fdate = file.DateLastModified`

Comment: Thanks. The log file can be checked fine but it doesn't jump to eh? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @aab, then you'll have to debug it. Step through, inspect the variable to see why it behaves the way it does.

Comment: The date last modified is obtained fine but the code goes past the following line `If Fdate = Date Then GoTo eh`, instead of jumping to `eh` like its supposed to. I'm wondering if it has to do with `Fdate` showing both `date/time` and `Date` only showing `date`. What do you think?

Comment: You guessed it right =) @aab. Look at the integer part of the date to compare. For example > `If Int(file.DateLastModified) = Date Then`

Comment: Indeed. Clearly if you can see a difference they are not the same.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the trailing `\` in `file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Logs.txt\"`

Comment: The trailing backslash is not a problem. Works either way.